# Why is this attack complexity equal that exact number of bit operations?

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis, attack, complexity, 2nd-preimage-resistance

in the [this paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/602.pdf#page=4),section 3,autors attack hamsi-256. Im trying to make a parametrized version, so i need to understand how do they estimate the complexity of attack in bit operations,that reads as followed
[image]
[image]
[image]
Can anybody say why they dont count number of operations to generate a tree with $2^{224}$ leaves,and why is the summ looks like that? I know im asking a hard question, but i have noone to explaing such thing to me.